# Including 3rd party libraries in my code

Tags: licensing

My question is regarding the legal aspect of including free open source 3rd party libraries in my commercial software. As an example, I have used the c# library MySqlBackup.NET to be able to backup and restore a MySQL database from my C# app. The license page of the 3rd party library website states:

"Anyone is free to copy, modify, publish, use, compile, sell, or
distribute this software, either in source code form or as a compiled
binary, for any purpose, commercial or non-commercial, and by any
means."

The rest of the license can be read [here](https://mysqlbackupnet.codeplex.com/license). Is it correct that I must have a reference of this is my own Terms and Conditions? If so, what is the correct way to go about this? Perhaps as an Appendix at the end?

Answer (score 1):

The license in question is the [Unlicense](http://unlicense.org/). You don't have to do anything.

You may want to make a note of where you got it from, just so that whenever someone comes across this code later and wonders who wrote it. But that's up to you.

Comment: Thank you. Perhaps that library doesn't apply for my question. I have other 3rd party libraries which use different licenses such as this one http://www.codeproject.com/info/cpol10.aspx It states under Restrictions that I must include this license with all distributions of my executable. How exactly is that achieved?

Comment: Another would be this one https://sshnet.codeplex.com/license

Comment: You need to ask a different answer for a different license, there is no single answer that can cover all known licenses.

Comment: As a side note and irrespective if the license of this utility if it combined in certain ways with MySQL, the GPL of MySQL may apply too.